# How to get part of a string[] array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, collections

How, using C#, can I create a new string[] from another string[] containing a subsection of the old string[] array?

For example, if I had:

```
string[] a = { "cat", "dog", "hamster", "parrot" }
```

And I wanted to get everything after the first element I should get:

```
string[] b = { "dog", "hamster", "parrot" }
```

How, if this is even possible without a for loop, do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use some extensions methods to solve it, that is the case for [`Skip(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) under the `System.Linq` namespace, for sample:

```
string[] b = a.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

And it will skip `1` element and convert the result into a new array. Remember to add the namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

As the MSDN documentation said:

> Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns
>   the remaining elements.